# updating dynamic properties in grid properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties, propertygrid, dynamic-properties

I'm trying to use property grid to show object property. I have three drop-down lists whose items are dependent on what user selected. I mean that I use dynamic properties and create these properties in run-time. There is a problem here that I explain it with an example.
there are three drop down list: vendor, product and version. vendor and product are created from enum type  and version is created from a list type. when user click on vendor and select an item if item is linux, product must show turboLinux, alt_linux. when User select redhat vendor, product must show enterprise_linux . version items also change according to user selections. 
problem is updating isn't happen immediately after changing. look at this pictures please :

In this picture all things are correct

[image: in this picture all things are correct]

when user click  on vendor and choose redhat :

[image]

After each change I set property grid selected object with a new properties.
but changes applied when I click again on the object with a new properties.

this image is captured after clicking on the object

[image]

I have try INotifyPropertyChanged but nothing has changed.

Comment: I would suggest posting the code you've written.

Comment: @smead   my codes are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489309/dynamic-drop-down-list-as-a-dynamic-properties-in-propertygrid-c-sharp-net

Comment: I'll add my code here too

Comment: @smead do you know what is the problem?